# Specify position of combo box

Tags: python, combobox, bokeh

I have the following script that generates a combo box (`Select`) and a plot:

```
import bokeh.plotting as bk
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Plot
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select
from bokeh.simpleapp import simpleapp

data = {"a": {"x": [1,2,3], "y": [1,2,3]},
        "b": {"x": [3,2,1], "y": [1,2,3]},
        "c": {"x": [2,2,2], "y": [1,2,3]},}


options = ["a", "b", "c"]
select1 = Select(name = 'ticker1', value = options[0], options = options)

@simpleapp(select1)
def test_layout(ticker1):
    p = bk.figure(title = "layout test")

    chart_data = data[ticker1]

    df = ColumnDataSource(data = chart_data)
    p.circle(x = chart_data["x"], y = chart_data["y"])

    return p

test_layout.route("/bokeh/layout/")
```

This works just fine. However, I found no possibility to specify the position of the combo box.

My goal is, that the **combo box is displayed above the plot** (and not on the left side). How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to customize your simpleapp layout by implementing a function that actually builds your layout and then wrap it with the `layout` decorator. In your case it'd be test_layout.layout decorator. To do so you need to change the code a bit. Here's a version that should do what you need:

```
import bokeh.plotting as bk
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Plot
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select, AppVBox
from bokeh.simpleapp import simpleapp

data = {"a": {"x": [1,2,3], "y": [1,2,3]},
        "b": {"x": [3,2,1], "y": [1,2,3]},
        "c": {"x": [2,2,2], "y": [1,2,3]},}


options = ["a", "b", "c"]
select1 = Select(name = 'ticker1', value = options[0], options =     options)

@simpleapp(select1)
def test_layout(ticker1):
    p = bk.figure(title = "layout test")

    chart_data = data[ticker1]

    df = ColumnDataSource(data = chart_data)
    p.circle(x = chart_data["x"], y = chart_data["y"])

    return {'plot': p}

@test_layout.layout
def layout(app):
    return AppVBox(app=app, children=['ticker1', 'plot'])

test_layout.route("/bokeh/layout/")
```