# Save simpleapp bokeh plot to standalone html file

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

The following script (from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29540458/1251007)) generates a simpleapp Bokeh plot.

**How can I save the output to a standalone html file?**

```
import bokeh.plotting as bk
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Plot
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select, AppVBox
from bokeh.simpleapp import simpleapp

data = {"a": {"x": [1,2,3], "y": [1,2,3]},
        "b": {"x": [3,2,1], "y": [1,2,3]},
        "c": {"x": [2,2,2], "y": [1,2,3]},}


options = ["a", "b", "c"]
select1 = Select(name = 'ticker1', value = options[0], options = options)

@simpleapp(select1)
def test_layout(ticker1):
    p = bk.figure(title = "layout test")

    chart_data = data[ticker1]

    df = ColumnDataSource(data = chart_data)
    p.circle(x = chart_data["x"], y = chart_data["y"])

    return {'plot': p}

@test_layout.layout
def layout(app):
    return AppVBox(app=app, children=['ticker1', 'plot'])

test_layout.route("/bokeh/layout/")
```

I tried changing the `layout(app)` to make use of `file_html`. This generates the initial plot, but the combobox does not work. I think that `file_html` is only for single plot objects, not for something like the `simpleapp` that I'm using.

```
from bokeh.embed import file_html
from bokeh.resources import CDN

def layout(app):
    # save standalone html
    html = file_html(AppVBox(app=app, children=['ticker1', 'plot']), CDN, "title")
    f = open("bokeh_standalone.html", "w")
    f.write(html)
    f.close
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't too much documentation surrounding Bokeh at the moment so some simple tasks may seem a little under-supported. **TL;DR:** Use the example provided [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/sliders_applet) by extending it.

However, what you need to do in order to enable the Select box is to call `on_change('value', func)` on it, where `func` is a callable that updates the datasource. Once that has been done, you can set `datasource._dirty = True`. Importantly, all of these things must happen inside *another* method belonging to the app class called `setup_events`.

The way the bokeh server handles interaction is to create new python instances of objects that are stored in it's chosen internal database (redis by default). This means it is necessary to "setup events" every time.

I *strongly* suggest reading through the Sliders App example provided by ContinuumIO on the Bokeh Github page: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/sliders_applet

I've been pulling hair out over this for the last few weeks but we're understanding more and more everyday. I hope this helps :)